# How to exclude some stylecop rule in visual studio 2013

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, stylecop

I'm using visual studio 2013.

I install stylecop using NuGet Package follow these steps:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild/

Previously when I using visual studio 2010, I usually put my custom rules set called Setting.StyleCop file to my solution or project.

How should I implement my custom rules set in VS 2013?

Comment: Just do the same thing that you always did? I don't see how this is much different. What's keeping you?

Comment: The different is, for VS 2013, Stylecop doesn't support automatically integration during the installation. That's where it all began.

Comment: You should still be able to add the `setting.Stylecop` file. Just pick the new XML File as a template and give it the right name.

Answer (score 2):

`Settings.StyleCop` still works as it did previously.

---

The `StyleCop.MsBuild` package performs a couple of actions:

**1.** Stores an instance of StyleCop.exe in the packages directory, this makes it portable between machines, build servers etc.. Namely `\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.49.1\tools` this is pretty much the same you would get with installing it, but its not in program files.

**2.** Makes changes to the csproj, namely:

```
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.49.1\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.Targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.49.1\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.Targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.49.1\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.Targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.49.1\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.Targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

All this basically does is point at the targets file so that it runs stylecop and adds in some requires for the package to be there before building.

**What you need to do to use StyleCop.Settings**
Copy it into the root of your solution, or the project file, then it should get picked up as usual. The easiest way is just to copy it from `\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.49.1\tools`